# Laravel or Nova have the same model attributes on updating Event and update Event

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Simple callback to trace *updating* event (the before *update* event):

```
protected static function booted()
   {
      static::updating(function (Question $question) {
         // $question->name will be the same as in the 'update' event which might look strange
      });

      static::update(function (Question $question) {

      });
   }
```

Why attributes of *updating* and *update* events are the same?

Answer (score 2):

To get the previous value you should use *getOriginal* method:

```
if ($question->name != $question->getOriginal('name')) {
   // this value was changed so you may add more logic
}
```

Same applicable to *creating* and *created* events.